# How to layout 2 buttons on one panel using BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing

I recently found out that you can put a JPanel inside another JPanel, I tried it and it didn't quite do what I expected.
I'm trying to have one button in the center and one button on the bottom right of the panel, I'm using a BorderLayout for all my panels.
When I tried using two panels inside the center panel, the two panels were on the same line, but I've coded that one needed to be on the top and one on the bottom.
Does anyone know how I could resolve this?
Sorry for not adding the code in the place, wasn't sure and I had already deleted it so I quickly made this, it is the same code I used in my project.
My code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JButton btn = new JButton();
JPanel center = new JPanel();
JPanel top = new JPanel();
JPanel bot = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

bot.add(btn);

center.add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
center.add(bot, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

frame.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

When I use this code, "bot" is going to be displayed on the right of "top".
I think it has to do with the layout of "center" but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you show us the code, so we can see what might be wrong?

Comment: @maloomeister Sorry that I didn't add the code, I've added the code now. I hope it's of any help.

Comment: Did you make sure you set the Layout-Manager correctly? As in `setLayout(new BorderLayout())`. Because your example code does not include that.

Comment: The default layout of `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, that helped a lot. I did forget to set all the layouts for the panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `LayoutManager` of `center` to `BorderLayout`, with this method:

```
center.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```